# Common way to change configuration in hawtio

Tags: tomcat, hawtio

I have my own WAR with activemq and some camel routes which I want to deploy on Tomcat7. To monitor the queues and the routes I want to use hawtio.
Therefore I downloaded the hawtio-default.war (hawtio 1.4.24) deployed it on my tomcat. 
This works fine. But I wanted to enable authentication and disable git. 
Therefore I changed the configuration by adding following lines to the bluepringt.properties:

```
hawtio.offline=true
hawtio.dirname=${catalina.base}/hawtio
hawtio.config.dir=${hawtio.dirname}/config
hawtio.config.cloneOnStartup=false
hawtio.config.pullOnStartup=false
hawtio.authenticationEnabled=true
```

I got those configs from the [configuration help page](http://hawt.io/configuration/index.html) .

I restarted the server. The dir is used correctly but the authentication is still disabled.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately the hawtio.authenticationEnabled setting can only be set via a system property or as an env-entry, setting it via a blueprint XML file will have no effect.